# Calculate differences on a variable between factor levels

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with exactly one value measured for each subject at multiple timepoints. It simplifies to this:

```py
> set.seed(42)
> x = data.frame(subject=rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 3), time=rep(c(1,2,3), each=3), value=rnorm(3*3, 0, 1))
> x
  subject time       value
1       a    1  1.37095845
2       b    1 -0.56469817
3       c    1  0.36312841
4       a    2  0.63286260
5       b    2  0.40426832
6       c    2 -0.10612452
7       a    3  1.51152200
8       b    3 -0.09465904
9       c    3  2.01842371
```

I want to calculate the change in `value` for each timepoint and for each subject. For this simple example, my My current solution is this:

```py
> x$diff[x$time==1] = x$value[x$time==2] - x$value[x$time==1]
> x$diff[x$time==2] = x$value[x$time==3] - x$value[x$time==2]
> x
  subject time       value       diff
1       a    1  1.37095845 -0.7380958
2       b    1 -0.56469817  0.9689665
3       c    1  0.36312841 -0.4692529
4       a    2  0.63286260  0.8786594
5       b    2  0.40426832 -0.4989274
6       c    2 -0.10612452  2.1245482
7       a    3  1.51152200         NA
8       b    3 -0.09465904         NA
9       c    3  2.01842371         NA
```

... and then remove the last rows. However, in my actual data set, there's way more levels of `time` and I need to do this for several columns instead of just `value`. The code gets very ugly. Is there a neat way to do this? A solution which does not assume that rows are ordered within subjects according to `time` would be nice.

Comment: Your example would be much easier to reproduce with `?set.seed`

Comment: Example updated with set.seed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(x)`), grouped by 'subject', we take the difference of the next value (`shift(value, type='lead')`) with the current value and assign (`:=`) the output to create the 'Diff' column.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(x)[order(time),Diff := shift(value, type= 'lead') - value ,
                                              by = subject]
#   subject time       value       Diff
#1:       a    1  1.37095845 -0.7380958
#2:       b    1 -0.56469817  0.9689665
#3:       c    1  0.36312841 -0.4692529
#4:       a    2  0.63286260  0.8786594
#5:       b    2  0.40426832 -0.4989274
#6:       c    2 -0.10612452  2.1245482
#7:       a    3  1.51152200         NA
#8:       b    3 -0.09465904         NA
#9:       c    3  2.01842371         NA
```

Comment: @JonasLindeløv  You could use `setDF` to convert back to `data.frame`

Comment: @JonasLindeløv  It is easy to fix, just use `order(time)` in the i. (updated)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dplyr` for this:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  arrange(time, subject) %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  mutate(diff = c(diff(value), NA))
# Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
# Groups: subject [3]
# 
#   subject  time       value        diff
#    (fctr) (dbl)       (dbl)       (dbl)
# 1       a     1  1.30970525 -1.66596287
# 2       b     1  0.12556761 -0.06070412
# 3       c     1 -1.09423634  1.38590546
# 4       a     2 -0.35625763  0.91417329
# 5       b     2  0.06486349  0.06652424
# 6       c     2  0.29166912 -0.98495562
# 7       a     3  0.55791566          NA
# 8       b     3  0.13138773          NA
# 9       c     3 -0.69328649          NA
```

If you want to get rid of the `NA`s, add `%>% na.omit`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `ave`. `ave` applies a function to a subset of a values, for more details see `?ave`, e.g.:

```
x$diff <- ave(x$value, x$subject, FUN=function(x)c(diff(x), NA))
x
#   subject time       value       diff
# 1       a    1  1.37095845 -0.7380958
# 2       b    1 -0.56469817  0.9689665
# 3       c    1  0.36312841 -0.4692529
# 4       a    2  0.63286260  0.8786594
# 5       b    2  0.40426832 -0.4989274
# 6       c    2 -0.10612452  2.1245482
# 7       a    3  1.51152200         NA
# 8       b    3 -0.09465904         NA
# 9       c    3  2.01842371         NA
```

BTW the `diff` function requires that the `time` is ordered.

EDIT: Update with `set.seed(42)`.